# Compare array values with another array and return value depending on combinations using ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the following array

```
prime_arr = [2,3,5,7,11,13]
```

and I need to check whether the array has 3, 5  7 and return the value(s) differ based on presence

If it has 3 alone return "Yes" and 5 alone return "it is " and  7 alone return "done" and

If it has [3,5] return "Yes it is "

If it has [3,5,7] return "Yes it is done"

The return value should differ based on combination

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about the other three combinations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this looks a lot like homework (and since no one here is paid to write your code for you), I'm not going to give you the actual answer. I will however give you some pointers to pieces of the puzzle - hopefully you'll be able to piece them together.

You can find the intersection between two arrays using the [`#&`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-26) method. So:

```
prime_arr = [2,3,5,7,11,13]
# => [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
prime_arr & [3]
# => [3]
prime_arr & [3,5]
# => [3, 5]
prime_arr & [3,5,7]
# => [3, 5, 7]
prime_arr & [4]
# => []
```

A case statement can toggle on Array values, like so:

```
a = [1,2]
case a
  when [1]; "just one"
  when [1,2]; "both"
end
# => "both"
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for help but here we need to write the cases for every combination where the code doesnot smell good.. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
words = ['Yes', 'it is', 'done']
prime_arr = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
target = [3, 5, 7]

words.take((prime_arr & target).size).join(" ")
```

Edited:

```
prime_arr = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
mapping = {
  [3] => 'Yes',
  [3, 5] => 'Yes it is',
  [3, 5, 7] => 'Yes it is done'
}

mapping[prime_arr & [3, 5, 7]] # => 'Yes it is done'
mapping[prime_arr & [3, 5]] # => 'Yes it is'
mapping[prime_arr & [3]] # => 'Yes'
```

You get a nil when none of the keys in `mapping` matches.

Comment: Thanks for answer.But it fails when it is 5 and 7 alone it returns "Yes" as we are depending on the size.any alternate appreciated

Comment: Ah, did not take this into account. Will edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the other three cases you haven't made clear, so I am guessing.

```
[[3, 5, 7], ["Yes ", "it is ", "done"]]
.transpose.each.with_object(""){|(i, w), s| s << w if prime_arr.include?(i)}
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for help
Actually I am getting the Prime Factors of given number in to one array.(prime_arr)
If it has other than specified values it should return the Given number.